# unexpected behavior non-equi join data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

Consider some sample data

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(foo = 1:4, bar = letters[1:4])
dt2 <- data.table(foo1 = 2:5, bar1 = LETTERS[1:4])
```

I am trying to join these two sample data.tables by non-equi join (which also needs me to set cartesian join option):

```
options("datatable.allow.cartesian" = T)
dt3 <- dt1[dt2, on = .(foo < foo1), nomatch = 0L]
```

`dt3` comes out to be:

```
    foo bar bar1
 1:   2   a    A
 2:   3   a    B
 3:   3   b    B
 4:   4   a    C
 5:   4   b    C
 6:   4   c    C
 7:   5   a    D
 8:   5   b    D
 9:   5   c    D
10:   5   d    D
```

However there are 2 problems with this:

1. column `foo` don't have value 5 (thats an obvious bug)
2. column `foo1` is not present in output (which could be limiting for further conditions; if any)

In order to bypass second condition I tried:

```
dt2[, foo11 := foo1]
dt4 <- dt1[dt2, on = .(foo < foo1), nomatch = 0L]
options("datatable.allow.cartesian" = F)
```

which gives me `dt4`:

```
    foo bar bar1 foo11
 1:   2   a    A     2
 2:   3   a    B     3
 3:   3   b    B     3
 4:   4   a    C     4
 5:   4   b    C     4
 6:   4   c    C     4
 7:   5   a    D     5
 8:   5   b    D     5
 9:   5   c    D     5
10:   5   d    D     5
```

So here `foo11` is essentially a copy of errorneous column `foo` which looks like another bug due to non-equi join.

Am I missing any point or doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the behavior is the expected, except for the variable being named quite surprisingly. I made a little tweak to your sample data to show that everything is alright:

```
dt1 <- data.table(foo = 1:4, bar = letters[1:4])
dt2 <- data.table(foo1 = 2:4, bar1 = letters[2:4]) # small change here

dt1[dt2, on = .(foo < foo1), allow.cartesian = TRUE][dt1, on = "bar"]
    foo bar bar1 i.foo
 1:   2   a    b     1
 2:   3   a    c     1
 3:   4   a    d     1
 4:   5   a    e     1
 5:   3   b    c     2
 6:   4   b    d     2
 7:   5   b    e     2
 8:   4   c    d     3
 9:   5   c    e     3
10:   5   d    e     4
```

For me the behavior is the expected, it's just that the first column is named `foo` instead of `foo1`. That's why you see `fool1` as an erroneous copy of "erroneous foo`: it's actually a copy of`foo1`.

### EDIT: a possible workaround:

This isn't really elegant, but is a workaround:

```
dt1[dt2, .(foo = x.foo, foo1, bar, bar1), on = .(foo < foo1), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
    foo foo1 bar bar1
 1:   1    2   a    b
 2:   1    3   a    c
 3:   2    3   b    c
 4:   1    4   a    d
 5:   2    4   b    d
 6:   3    4   c    d
 7:   1    5   a    e
 8:   2    5   b    e
 9:   3    5   c    e
10:   4    5   d    e
```

`x.foo` retains the original, true `foo`. `foo1` still is what it is, so you can return both variables.

Comment: There's an open issue regarding this naming: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3437. As per the last release notes and news, the reactions to issues are being considered for prioritization of solutions, so you may consider giving it the "like" (top right corner of the original issue).

Comment: See also [SQL-like column return for non-equi and rolling joins](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/2706)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering as it unblocks me. Also pointing to the issue which I will like (Along with your answer :)). I like your edit more as it is cleaner with @Henrik link. Original answer to me looks more like a workaround in which you are joining table again.